# Edit Control Does Not Save Data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, crud

I'm trying to add Edit functionality to a CRUD app. I've put the code I'm using below. I can access the view and edit the data in the fields, but when I click save it's not saving the updated change to the database and hence, not displaying in the view.

```cs
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int Id)
{
    try
    {      
        Incident incident = _incidentManager.Get(Id);

        return View(incident);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        return View("Error", GetError(exc));           
    }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Incident incident)
{
    try
    {
        _incidentManager.Edit(incident);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        return View("Error", GetError(exc));
    }
}
```

It's not saving the changes to the database and I don't understand why.

Comment: You miss some code like " _incidentManager.Update(Incident);
                     _incidentManager.SaveChanges();""

Comment: Please provide code where you performing CRUD

Comment: What is `_incidentManager` and what does the `Edit` method do? The code you have shown doesn't include anything that does the save, so unless it's in `Edit` then, no, it won't save the changes. Please post more code.